# Cassandra Best Practices

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, nosql

What is the best practice to be used for Cassandra - separate installations for different applications or just a new keyspace in same installations.

Factors such has storage, memory and CPU how they can be restricted for a keyspace if we used the same cluster installation in shared model for different applications.

Regards